# Editing wc -l src Output

Tags: command-line, bash, awk, c, wc

I am new to the Topic and working on a few bash commands.

I am stuck at a task where i Need t ouput my result in a specific Format.

```
wc -l folder/*
```

The Output gives me:

```
0 folder/file1
3 folder/file2
3 total
```

I would like to have only the total output together with a String like:

```
The total number of lines is: numberOfLines
```

How is it possible to format my output / reduce it to a single line?
I looked a bit into awk commands but I was not able to make it work.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to get a grand total is to concatenate the files first, and pass the concatenation to `wc`.

Ex.

```
printf 'The total number of lines is: %d\n' "$(cat folder/* | wc -l)"
```

However if you want to use awk, here's how I'd do it:

```
wc -l folder/* | awk 'END{print "The total number of lines is: " $1}'
```

Comment: You probably meant `wc -l folder/* | awk '$2 == "total" {print "..." $1}'`

Comment: @glennjackman oops thanks - I've gone with a slight variant

Comment: or even `awk 'END{ print "The total number of lines is: " NR}' files*`